# Is it possible to use reduce with strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I wanted to know is it possible to use the `reduce` method on arrays with strings as well?

For ex: If I have an array like this: `[ 'm', 'o', 'o', 'n' ]` then I can reduce it to an object like this: `{ m: 1, o: 2, n: 1 }`, that counts the occurrences of all characters in the string.

But if instead I had a string `"moon"` I wouldn't be able to use the `reduce` method with it.

I know I can write a custom implementation for `reduce`, but is there something simpler?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, since [Array.prototype.reduce](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce) is a generic method, it doesn't require it's `this` value to *necessarily* be an array. Meaning `reduce` is designed *not* only to work with arrays but to also work with other *array-like* values like strings.

And in order to use `reduce` with the string `str`, you can invoke it on the string by using [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

```js
const str = "moon";
const strCharCount = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
  str,
  (r, s) => {
    r[s] = (r[s] ?? 0) + 1;
    return r;
  },
  {}
);

console.log(strCharCount);
```

And if all of that didn't make any sense, you can also transform the string to an array and use `reduce` as you normally would.

```js
const str = "moon";
const strCharCount = Array.from(str).reduce((r, s) => {
  r[s] = (r[s] ?? 0) + 1;
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(strCharCount);
```